# Split text into different columns and write in an excel file using xlsxwriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am trying to split a line which has commas and write the splitted values in different columns

```
a,b
```

```
c,d
```

```
e,f
```

I need an excel file as below

[image]

I used  worksheet.write (row,column,line) option to write into a file but unable to split the data into columns

Output I got

[image]

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: for x in range (0,len(list)):
line=linelist{x]
worksheet.write(x,0,line)
workbook.close()

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code sample;

```
for x in range (0,len(list)): 
    line=linelist{x] 
    worksheet.write(x,0,line) 

workbook.close()
```

1. Is your list name 'linelist'? if so what is `len(list)` going to return? I assume that you want the length of the list so it should be `for x in range(0,len(linelist))`
2. `line=linelist{x]` opens with a curly bracket and closes with a square bracket. Should be open and close square brackets.
3. `worksheet.write(x,0,line)` is varying the row co-ordinate while leaving the column co-ordinate as 0 for all values in the list. You don't show what the list contains but either way this will only write down column 'A' for each element in the list. If you want to write a list across the row then you need to vary the column co-ordinate

You can modify your code to this to write one list across one row.

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('foo.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

linelist = ['a', 'b']

for x in range (0,len(linelist)): 
    line=linelist[x] 
    worksheet.write(0,x,line) 
  
workbook.close()
```

You can also use a list directly or convert comma separated strings to lists, and use write_row instead;

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('foo.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

 
linelist = ['a', 'b']  # List
row2 = 'c,d'  # Comma separated string
row3 = 'e,f'

### Use write_row to write the string across the row
worksheet.write_row('A1', linelist)
worksheet.write_row('A2', row2.split(','))
worksheet.write_row('A3', row3.split(','))

workbook.close()
```